# Mobilefirst CLI 'Error:No Platform were detected' while giving command 'mfpdev app register' even after android platform added

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I created cordova app by 'cordova create UserLogin com.example.userlogin UserLogin --template cordova-template-mfp'. And I added android platform by 'cordova platform add android'. I tried to register to local mfp by 'mfpdev app register'. But I am getting error 'No Platform were detected' even after android platform added.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In which folder are you running the "mfpdev app register" command? You have to be running this command in the project's root folder.

Comment: I ran 'mfpdev app register' in Project's root folder. Please visit sequence of commands in screen shot at https://i.stack.imgur.com/987Fg.png. Thank you for your response.

**The commands are:**
1) cordova create UserLogin com.example.userlogin UserLogin --template cordova-template-mfp
2) cd UserLogin
3) cordova platform add android (after this 'cordova emulate android' is successfully installed on emulator)
4) mfpdev app register
    
   Verifying server configuration...
   Registering to server:'http://10.xxx.188.17:9080' runtime:'mfp'
   Error: No platforms were detected.

Comment: Can you please share the version of the plugin cordova-plugin-mfp installed?

Comment: @Keerthi madam..! cordova-plugin-mfp versions is <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mfp" spec="~8.0" />. And cordova version-8.1.0 & mfpdev version-8.0.0-2018121711. Thank you.

Comment: When I run 'cordova plugin list' command, I got 'cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2019120904 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"' . Thank you.